# Summing in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have 3 different queries from different tables in same database

```
 $sum = "SELECT htno, SUM(tm) AS tech FROM table1 WHERE htno='$id'";

 $sum1 = "SELECT htno, SUM(em) AS tech1 FROM table2 WHERE htno='$id'";

 $sum2= "SELECT htno, SUM(hm) AS tech2 FROM table3 WHERE htno='$id'";
```

Now i want to add tech, tech1 and tech2

Comment: will i get job after Summing  ???

Comment: Show the table schemas. is `htno` a PK?

Comment: will it work? without a group by condition?

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it as easy as this?

```
SELECT htno, SUM(tm) + SUM(em) + SUM(hm),....
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT x.htno, SUM(x.tech)
FROM
    (
        SELECT htno, SUM(tm) AS tech FROM....WHERE...GROUP BY...
        UNION ALL
        SELECT htno, SUM(em) AS tech  FROM....WHERE...GROUP BY...
        UNION ALL
        SELECT htno, SUM(hm) AS tech  FROM....WHERE...GROUP BY...
    ) x
GROUP BY x.htno
```

Comment: sum(tm) consists of one table, sum(em) consists of anaother table n viceversa

Comment: post your whole query so we can create a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT htno, 
       Sum(tm) + Sum(em) + Sum(hm) AS tech4 
FROM   table1 
       INNER JOIN table2 
              ON table1.htno = table2.htno 
       INNER JOIN table3 
              ON table3.htno = table2.htno 
GROUP  BY table1.htno
```